# Putting a Time Limit On User Input

Tags: c, input

I am trying to put a time limit on the user input, so if they take longer than 2 seconds to put type in an input then the program will terminate. I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this in C language?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to read in? If it's more then one character: 2 seconds until the first or last character read in?

Comment: I want to read in an int

Comment: An `int` with more then one digit? If yes you might like to answer the second part of my previous question?

Comment: i want to read in something like 2(space)3(space)5

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this through signal handling,you have to handle SIGALARM signal in your code.

```
void AlrmSigHnd(int signo)
{
exit(0);
}
int main()
{
void(*SigHnd)(int);
SigHnd = AlrSigHnd;

signal(SIGALRM,SigHnd);
alarm(2); // AlrmSigHnd will called after 2 seconds.
scanf("%d",&i);  
alarm(0); // Cancel signal registration
}
```

Comment: I used this, but got errors.. It says "incompatible implicit declaration of exit(0)".. Do you know what might be wrong? I have included the signal.h header as well

Comment: @user2159166 Hey include stdlib.h for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use select with a timeout, checking the stdin. So if select returns an empty fd set you know that the timeout has expired, if it returns the set with stdin, then you loop again and keep reading your input.

Unfortunately this approach doesn't let you easily read one int directly, but it works without using a signal handler.